# same Firestore realtime database for client and user

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make a Flutter app for showing shop details. I stored data in the Firestore real-time database. It's working perfectly.

What I want to do now is make another app for the owner, then he can change data in Firestore and also send push notifications to shop app users.

Is this possible? It would be helpful If you have any tutorials or videos.I haven't tried cloud functions because they need a credit card, Which I don't have.

Comment: To be really honest I don't understand why you would want to make a whole new different app. It would be easier to just set a different String to the user. Since you probably authenticate via Firebase you can make a user profile with "name: something, role: customer, or role: owner" and then conditionally change a few things in your app. It would be ALOT easier than building and maintaining two apps. There are a million videos available on youtube on how to mutate data in the real time database. I don't know why you need a credit card for that...

Comment: I forget to mention, I am beginner in Flutter, Firebase and whole programming world

Comment: credit card is needed for cloud functions and google map - for billing account creation

Comment: actually I try to create a Ecommerce like app, which shows user products of the app. When it sold out, owner need to delete the item. that's why I said making another app.

Comment: is there any example?

Comment: @Wicked Gummy Bear, wouldn't putting the code of admin side into the same app may enlarge the app size in mega projects like Ecommerce app?

Comment: yes, I do not want that. my app users have no authorization too. Because it's only for showing products. So I dont want to make admin area just for the owner.

Comment: If that is the case then you should make two app yes.. But if you ask me, the code for a admin side is relatively small. Compared to making a whole new app. But I don't really see the problem in the question. If both apps have the same communication-ish with fireStore then the user can only see stuff and the admin with the other app can delete things. If you use the realtime database the changes are instant.

Either way you will need to make an app with login to firebase to see the database. Only small difference is that the admin app has a few extra options to delete it.

Comment: I would show you examples but to be honest you should just look for them on youtube. I think most examples use the provider way with streambuilder. But since there are other architectures out there like BLoC and Stacked I cannot tell you which way you should go. Unfortunately I cannot give you a clear cut and dry answer which you can just copy and paste and have your app.

You can build a pretty big portion of you app without cloud functions and add those in later

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments. I already used streambuilder for users app. I just want to know How to use the same firestore database used by users app with admin app?

Comment: When I created another project for the admin app in firebase. It won't show user's firestore database in this project? So the question is how to use the same firestore database for both users and admin app? Admin app can edit database data