# No Free tier for Cloud Functions - Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I was just making an app for Flutter learning cloud functions. When I check on a tutorial, cloud functions in firebase was free. But now I checked.

[image]

It's not, it's said to upgrade. Then I checked the pricing page,
So my question is if I upgrade, I lose spark plan, I need to pay for it? Is there any way to get spark plan just for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I upgrade, I lose spark plan, I need to pay for it?

You can create multiple projects, some on the free plan, and others paid.  You can also remove the payment plan and go back to spark.  As such, you will not "lose spark plan" if you choose to upgrade in order to use Functions in a project.

> Is there any way to get spark plan just for testing?

After March 15, there will be no more option to use Functions for free on the Spark plan.  Existing projects will be forced to upgrade, of functions will stop working

You should know that, even if you upgrade to a payment plan, there is a very generous free allowance that gives you use of functions without actually having to pay money.  See the details on the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/).  You get 2 million invocations per month. I think you'll find that very difficult to exhaust if you are just testing.

Also, you can always use the [Firebase local emulators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) for free.

Comment: So they will only pay after I exceed spark plan free allowance in blaze plan. is it?

Comment: sorry, I am not a native english speaker. So just to confirm

Comment: You will only pay after the free monthly allowance is exceeded for each product you use.  You can track usage in the dashboard.

Comment: one doubt, not about the above. is Firebase allows to share same firestore database for different apps? One for just viewing data, the other for editing data in firestore.

Comment: If you have new questions, please post them separately.

Comment: I already did... but no one answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65352286/same-firestore-realtime-database-for-client-and-user

Comment: Your other question is asking for references to tutorials, which is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Maybe, but now I want to know is there any way to share the same firestore database for different apps?

Comment: Yes, there is, but such a question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Post to a site that allows for open-ended questions or opinions, such as Reddit.

Answer (score 0):

https://firebase.google.com/pricing

Yes you can downgrade from plans.

Comment: I have seen now this "k
Free usage from Spark plan included*" in top of the pricing plan. make me confuse?

Comment: I am not a native english speaker